# Using Javascipt to fade between browser background colours

Tags: javascript, html, background

First post, starting to explore JS.

I am using elearning software called Articualte Storyline. I export everything in my courses in html. It is basically a supercharged Powerpoint but one of the options is to create a trigger to run JS which opens up lots of additional options.

I have been using the JS below to set the browser background colour to something of my choosing.
I have then repeated the code on the next slide, so when the user moves through the exported course it changes the background colour.

However, this change of colour is very abrupt so I would prefer it to slowly fade between colour 1 and colour 2.

I imagine that on the second slide, I instruct the colour to be colour 1, then after a delay transition to the new colour 2, but I have become stuck!

Any help gratefully received, thanks!

document.body.style.background="linear-gradient(120deg, #f093fb 0%, #f5576c 100%)";

Answer (score 0):

Use a transition in the CSS

```js
function rand() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
}

function randomBG() {
  var bgColor = "rgb(" + rand() + "," + rand() + "," + rand() + ")";
  document.body.style.background = bgColor;
}

window.setInterval(randomBG, 2000);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #AAEE33;
  transition: background 500ms linear;
}
```

Comment: While the OP specifically asked for a JavaScript solution I think this is the best solution.

Comment: This solution will not work for OP, as they are asking about transitioning `linear-gradient` background images (not solid colors).  https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_transition_gradients

Comment: Thanks all! 
epascarello, that worked and showed randomised colours displaying at intervals. 
Mike and Jon, yes a JS solution would be best as that seems to be what I can trigger from my software.

Comment: AH, brain fart of the transition with linear, it can be done with some JavaScript code. I do not have time to write that solution now.

Comment: Dont worry! Decided to concentrate on solid colours at present! Will keep digging :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
document.body.style.transition = "background 0.5s ease;"
```

Comment: This solution will not work for OP, as they are asking about transitioning `linear-gradient` background images (not solid colors).  https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_transition_gradients

Comment: thanks Jon and Costa. If I was to concentrate on solid colours for now, how could I use that JS to transition between two colours? Set the background to colour1, then trigger that JS, then set it to colour 2? 

Appreciate your input, promise I will sign myself up to do some proper JS learning after this!